# Identifying non-sequential tibble columns by index, position or number in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

A fairly common data issue in some circles is coding an instrument, for example this one, where related items are separated in the instrument. The idea is to avoid cuing the respondent that all of these questions - say all those beginning with A or D in this example, are related.

```
rm(list=ls())
Column_Names = c('A2','B1','D1','A1','B3','B2','D3','A3','A4','D2')
Matrix <- matrix(nrow=10,ncol=10,floor(runif(n=100,min=0, max=10)))
Data <- as_tibble(Matrix)
names(Data) = Column_Names
Identifier = sample(letters, size=10)
Data <- Data %>% mutate(Identifier = Identifier)
rm(Matrix, Column_Names, Identifier)
```

Scoring these instruments typically requires you to take all the related items (B1, B2, B2,,) and do something with them. This is often something very simple - a mean, and it may be the case that some items have to be recoded (0=9, 1=8, 2-7,3-6 ...). All of that is easy. Typically there are sub-scales (A,B,C,D here), and these are calculated on fixed subsets of the variables - A1,A2,A3 might be one subscale, and D1,D2 and D3 another, for example.

The hard bit is selecting the columns. What happens in real examples, is there might be 50 items, and they should be in a fixed order. (These instruments provide the questions in a fixed order). The tricky bit is that different investigators will use different NAMES for the SAME variables. They don't use names like the ones in my example, where each subscale has a name that refers directly to the subscale.

There are only two sane ways to do this, and get it right (I think). One is to rename the variables to a common set of names, and score these. The other is to pick the variables out by position - so subscale A is columns 1, 3 and 8, subscale B is columns 2,5 and 6.

This is trivial, if you put the variable numbers in your code.

```
Data %>% select(2,5,6) %>% names()
```

It's not very generalisable. I have a case where I have 70 variables, 8 subscales with 4 to 8 variables in each, and an overall score with 40 variables. I would like, but can't see a way, to read in the column numbers from a file, and pull them out.

```
Scales <- c('A','B','D')
Numbers <- c('1,4,8,9','2,5,6','3,7,10')
Scale <- tibble(Scales,Numbers)
```

I'd like to get them out

```
Data %>% select(2,5,6) %>% names()
```

works, but

```
    Data %>% select(Scale$Numbers[1]) %>% names()
    Data %>% select(as.numeric(Scale$Numbers[1])) %>% names()
```

don't, as do many efforts involving quo, !!, and the like. I know Hadley Wickham [disapproves of using column positions](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1462) and I get why, but this is a reasonable use case, maybe the only one I've ever come across.

This is what I'm doing for this particular study -

```
Somatic <- Questionnaire1 %>%
  select(   1,7,16,32,43,
          45,50,51, Identifier) %>%
  rowwise(Identifier) %>%
  mutate(Somatic = mean(c_across(1:8),na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  select(Identifier, Somatic)
  
Cognitive  <- Questionnaire %>%
  select( 2, 4, 8,11,15,
         21,22,23,36,42,
         46,54,59, Identifier) %>%
  rowwise(Identifier) %>%
  mutate(Cognitive = mean(c_across(1:13),na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  select(Identifier, Cognitive)
```

In this application, there are nine of these for 8 subclasses, and one overall score. In this study, there are 5 different instruments being used, with five different sets of variables, and a total of twenty subscales. This is why I want to have a programmatic solution.

Suggestions welcomed!
Thanks
Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a named list. Is this what you want?

```
Scales <- c('A','B','D')
Numbers = list(A = c(1,4,8,9), B = c(2,5,6), D = c(3, 7, 10))
Scale <- tibble(Scales,Numbers)
Data %>% select(Scale$Numbers$B) %>% names()
#[1] "B1" "B3" "B2"
```

We can also make this into a search function.

```
find <- function(x){
    Data %>% select(Scale$Numbers[[x]]) %>% names()
}

find("B")
#[1] "B1" "B3" "B2"
```

Comment: Doesn't work either - the general problem is that I might call them somethiing like Scale_Q_1, Scale_Q_2 ..., while another study might call them Question1, Question2, Question3, or Irritable, Cranky, Sad, or something much less usable. I've seen codes like BQX1 BQX4 BQG3 BQG5, in that order, and God knows where they came from. The only constant is the order of variables corresponds to the order of the questions,

Comment: This approach is not based on the names of the columns. It is based on whatever you name your list of column indeces in "Numbers". find("B") selects the indeces 2,5,6 and the names of those columns happen to be "B1", "B2", and "B3".

Comment: Ah - now I get it - apologies for being so slow, and thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like regardless you are going to need to create some type of mapping. Consider this approach to create a string of attributes that capture the group each question belongs to. I used "I" for the Identifier as the length needs to match the number of columns.

```
Attributes <- c("A", "B", "D", "A", "B", "B", "D", "A", "A", list(c("B", "D")), "I")
attr(Data, "Group") <- Attributes

Data %>%
    select_if(purrr::map_lgl(attr(Data, "Group"), `%in%`, x = "B")) %>% names()
#[1] "B1" "B3" "B2" "D2"
```

Comment: This is neat, and I'll go think about it, so thank you very much. I have the mappings in another file, so I'll need to think about how to refactor this file for this purpose. Numbers are more general, because one variable can, and often does, fit into more than one subscale.

Comment: I updated my example to show how one column could be assigned to multiple groups. In the case, I assigned column D2 to both groups B and D.  So when searching for group B, D2 also gets extracted.

Comment: I think this is very helpful. Clearly using columns indices cuts across the grain of dplyr, so this may be more practical - Thank you very much. I think I need to spend more time on purrr.

Comment: You could also consider creating a different attribute set for each group using 0 and 1 to indicate whether a column belongs in that group. It might be easier to derive the attribute string that way from your existing mapping table compared to nesting a list in the case more than one group applies. Then you call the associated attribute and where the values equal 1 when you want the applicable columns for a group.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach so you don't have to identify the column numbers in advance.

```
Data %>%
    select(starts_with("B")) %>%
    names()
#[1] "B1" "B3" "B2"
```

Comment: I appreciate this, but the real problem is that every investigator uses a different set of names. No solution that depends on names works for this situation - the only constant is that the questions come in a fixed order.